# Matrix printingPrinting reversed with loops

Tags: python, loops, matrix

I'm practicing looping with matrix, but I'm really stuck for an hour.

```
A = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
     [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
     [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
     [19, 22, 21, 22, 23, 24]]
```

Here is my Matrix and basically I'd like to change the loop sens on every line.

I have my function to print only values:

```
def clearPrint(Matrix):
i = 0
j = 0
result=[]
longLigne = len(Matrix)
longCol = len(Matrix[i])

for i in range(0, longLigne):
    print(" ")
    for j in range (0, longCol):
        result = Matrix[i][j] 
        print(result, end=" ")
```

And when it comes to switch the reverse the loop, I have no idea how..

And here is the result I'm trying to get

```
A = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
     [12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7],
     [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
     [24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19]]
```

Any advice, would be helpful

Answer (score 2):

One-liner:

```
A = [v[::-1] if i % 2 == 1 else v for i, v in enumerate(A)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
     [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
     [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
     [19, 22, 21, 22, 23, 24]]

for x in a:
    if a.index(x) % 2 != 0:
        print (x[::-1])
    else:
        print (x)
```

Output;

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7]
[13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
[24, 23, 22, 21, 22, 19]
>>>
```

`[::-1]` will reverse the lists.

Answer (score 0):

Another potential method:

```
def clearPrint(Matrix):
    for i in range(0, len(Matrix)):
        if i % 2 != 0:
            print(list(reversed(Matrix[i])))
        else:
            print(Matrix[i])

A = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
 [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
 [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
 [19, 22, 21, 22, 23, 24]]

clearPrint(A)
```

Comment: Oh, thank you, your code helped me a lot to understand !